# Is it possible to wire a second doorbell chime with only access to the transformer?

Tags: wiring, doorbell

(edited to adjust diagram per jsotola)

As I'm working from home I've missed a handful of times someone dropped off a package due to the doorbell being upstairs while I am downstairs. I'd like to add a second doorbell chime (single button still on the front door). I have access to the transformer in the utility room (I actually want to put the doorbell on the exact opposite wall), I just don't know if I can wire a second chime without doing a bunch of work pulling doorbell wire. Here is how I understand (note, I could be wrong, all the wiring is behind a wall) the current setup to be

[image]

I'm just not sure which of the two options below is the correct way to wire them. I believe I can manage the series wiring *if that is the correct way to wire a second chime*, but if not and the correct way is parallel that's out of my motivation range as I would need to snake wires through both exterior and interior walls.

[image]

Comment: your first drawing is probably incorrect ... electrically it is that way, but not physically ... the 2-wire cable from the button probably goes to the doorbell or to the transformer ... it does not split between the two places ... the split is accomplished by the use of another 2-wire cable

Comment: @jsotola I believe I have updated the pictures to better reflect what is likely, is that what you were thinking?

Comment: yes, much better

Comment: there is no reason to move the transformer connection from the left bell to the right bell in the series connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between parallel and series connection is just a difference in the connection of two wires.

The series connection may reduce the bell volume.

The parallel connection may overload the transformer.

[image]

Comment: Knowing that both will (probably) work is exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Neither actually
Assuming your doorbell wire is thick enough, you merely need to connect the chimes to the button and the and to the transformer.  And the runs can branch halfway -- you don't need to run two parallel lines to two chimes.

[image: diagram].

[image: Alternate wiring method]

Comment: So am I correct in my understanding that this still requires me to run a wire from the new chime to the doorbell?

Comment: yes, though you could have it branch off before it gets to the first doorbell, if that's more convenient

Comment: @gbronner I beleive that the drawing I've just added would do the trick as well, if I understood you correctly. It may be easier for the OP to do his wiring this way (from one chime directly to the other), instead of "home runs" back to the button & transformer. This may have been obvious and what you intended, but I wanted to be sure it was clear.

Comment: @FreeMan So am I correct in understanding that I'd just hook one doorbell to the other, so they'd be wired in parallel?

Comment: @Sidney  basically yes. You are using the terminals on the doorbell as a terminal block, so make sure that both are well connected.